# How can I use a variable to drop a table such as: DROP TABLE @dbname?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I use a variable to drop a table such as shown below?

This is a small part of a larger *.sql script, not a stored procedure. I could move it into one, although I'd like to avoid it if possible.

As is, it gives the error `Incorrect syntax near '@dbname'.`

```
DECLARE @dbname varchar(128) = 'Some_Name';

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = @dbname)
DROP TABLE @dbname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @tblname SYSNAME = 'Some_Name';
DECLARE @dropDDL NVARCHAR(1000) = 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tblname);

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE name = @tblname)
EXEC(@dropDDL)
```

Comment: Ahhh...dsql. I hadn't thought of that. Thank you.

Comment: `@dbname` is a odd choice for a variable intended to hold a table name, but it was the OP's. `DROP TABLE` probably works better than `DROP TBALE`. The `select` could be improved to limit the results to only user tables rather than any objects, Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: Oh good grief. You are correct, the variable name is not appropriate. Yes, it should be @tablename. I did not notice that. I've been working on the larger script too long & too late, and I became blind to it.